# Displaying the selected text from TextView into next activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I just want to display the selected text from `TextView` into next activity in Android. How could I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take that String value fron TextView and pass it in Bundle, so that it can be readable from to next activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToBeOpened.class);
Bundle pass = new Bundle();
pass.putString("str", "test");
intent.putExtra("INTENT_EXTRA_STRING", pass);
startActivity(intent);
```

and now It can be read in next activity from bundle in onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("INTENT_EXTRA_STRING")){
          Bundle data = getIntent().getBundleExtra("INTENT_EXTRA_STRING");
          String str = data.getString("str");
    }
}
```

Comment: suppose i have a textview with text as "Select text in your web browser and click the Spreed".if i select first two words(Select text) & click ok button,the first two words alone should be displayed in the next activity.How could i do.?pls help me.

Comment: So far i know Android 2.3 provides support for text selection. You can't select specific text in Android 2.2 and below.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selected", selectedText);
startActivity(intent);
```

in the next one:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String selected = (String)intent.getExtras().get("selected");
```

Comment: Thanks.how can i identify startpoint & endpoint of the selected text to display?